# Identify words from the string with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following text:

```
your salary $4500 is deposited in account ABC09-234-1234
your salary $4500 is deposited in account abc09-234-1234
```

I try with `(\d+)|([A-Z0-9-]+)` regex but it's not working with small letters.

I want to fetch `$4500` and `Account Number`.
Please help me with it .

Comment: Are the account number always at the end of the string? could you describe the format of an account number?

Comment: no no no @CasimiretHippolyte its not like that but i just want to identify the string like this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumptions**:

- Money values will always start with `$` and not contain spaces of any
  other non-numeric character
- Account number is always formatted in 3 'chunks' separated by `-`

**Solution**:

```
(\$\d+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+-[A-Za-z0-9]+-[A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/uG5uB2/1)

Comment: its working perfectly ... 
appriciate your help . :-)
@musefan

Comment: @jaydevthakkar: No worries, just accept whichever answer solved the problem best for you

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

- use `[A-Za-z0-9]`.
- use the `i` regex modifier, to make it case insensitive.

Bit like this:

```
/(\$\d+)|([A-Z0-9-]+)$/i
```

Edit: In light of your 'end of line' not being a firm anchor:

```
(\$\d+)|\b([A-Z0-9]*-[A-Z0-9]*)\b
```

This captures a sequence of letters and digits that *must* include a `-` symbol instead.

But you can perhaps simplify - if you assume that the *only* things you are interested are the substrings *ending with* a digit (which your examples are)

```
/(\S*\d)/
```

Will match on both your lines:

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP1yX1/2)

Comment: Your *like this* will match every word in the strings

Comment: Are you sure? My test run on regex101 gives me: https://regex101.com/r/jP1yX1/1 But it might be I need to move the end of line anchor.

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked the `$` anchor. But later comments from the OP have shiown that the account number may not be at the end of the line

Comment: Yes, that's a fair point. I'd started from the original data sample. I've amended further.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<salary>\$\d+)|\b(?<account>[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJ3iD3/5)

This regex will match `$4500`s like substrings (everywhere in the string) and `ABC09-234-1234`-like strings.

Comment: but if i write something after it then it will not works ...
**hello my salary is $3400 and my account is SBI09-213-1234 thank you**

Comment: I think it will now work OK, if you provided more specifications of the account ID, it would be easier. I assume it consists of numbers and letters and then hyphentated number sequences.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you want, but this solution may help you

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  my @words = grep /\d/, split;
  print "@words\n";
}


__DATA__
your salary $4500 is deposited in account ABC09-234-1234
your salary $4500 is deposited in account abc09-234-1234
```

#### output

```
$4500 ABC09-234-1234
$4500 abc09-234-1234
```